# DbAcl::check() - Failed ARO/ACO node lookup in permissions check.

Tags: cakephp, acl

i am using cakephp and use acl .
but i face this error .

```
DbAcl::check() - Failed ARO/ACO node lookup in permissions check.
```

thanks for help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible that you have added actions to your controllers and not updated the `aco` table. You can update your acos from the command line, using the `cake` shell.

To add an aco for the action `view` for the `UsersController`

```
cake acl create aco Users view
```

To add an aco for a new controller (e.g. for `PostsController`)

```
cake acl create aco controllers Posts
```

If find it most useful to have a script to automatically update acos. You can either write your own, or [try something like this aco_sync shell](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/generate-aco-records-for-your-controllers-and-actions-with-acosyncshell)

Answer (score 2):

Or Just exécute this commande in cake console 
cake AclExtras.AclExtras aco_sync
it'll update all the needed acos for the new views or controllers you just added
of Course you'll need the AclExtras Plugin.

Comment: Also for the cakephp 4.2.7 strawberry   run the command (windows) : 'cake acl.acl_extras aco_sync'   Will executed after you have installed aco extra plugin as mentioned by @Kamal Tahir