# how to manage plugin with cake's acl?

Tags: php, cakephp, acl

I am having trouble with cake's ACL.
My intention is to manage my plugins with ACL.

When I'm loading a page (pages/display), it works correct.

But, when I'm loading a page from my plugin (cms/users/index), I get the following:

> Warning (512): DbAcl::check() - Failed ARO/ACO node lookup in permissions check. Node references:
>   Aro: Array
>   (
>       [User] => Array
>           (
>               [id] => 1
>               [email] => email@email
>               [firstname] => admin
>               [lastname] => 
>               [zip] => 
>               [city] => 
>               [group_id] => 1
>               [created] => 1390647137
>               [modified] => 1390647137
>           )
>        )
>        Aco: controllers/Cms/Users/index [CORE\Cake\Model\Permission.php, line 92]

so, I have no idea what's going on here...

My aros_acos table has the folowing line:

```
id: 4;
aro_id: 5
aco_id: 15
_create / _read / _update / _delete = 1
```

My aro_id links to:

```
id: 5
parent_id: (null)
model: Group
foreign_key: 1
alias: (null)
lft: 1
rght: 4
```

My aco_id links to:

```
id: 15
parent_id: (null)
model: (null)
foreign_key: (null)
alias: controllers
lft: 1
rght: 30
```

This is a tree-structure, between 1 and 30, is the Cms-plugin (14, 15).

My question: it seems cake doesn't recognize the plugin-page.
How to fix this?

Many many thanks!

Greetz

Comment: this may help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049637/dbaclcheck-failed-aro-aco-node-lookup-in-permissions-check

Comment: Can you verify the ACO tree for me by running the following shell? `Console/cake acl view aco controllers`